# Trimming whitespace in Dart strings from beginning or end

Tags: dart

I am very new to Dart and am trying to get some sense of the basic libraries. For strings, there is a trim() function provided. This is good, but are there no obvious ways to trim whitespace only at the beginning or only at the end of a string?  I cannot find them.Thank you.

Comment: I agree that this is a strange gap. I complained about the same thing a while ago. It's currently set to be fixed by the next milestone. Please star this bug: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5589&q=ltrim&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Area%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no specific methods for trimming only leading or trailing whitespace. But it is quite easy to implement them:

```dart
/// trims leading whitespace
String ltrim(String str) {
  return str.replaceFirst(new RegExp(r"^\s+"), "");
}

/// trims trailing whitespace
String rtrim(String str) {
  return str.replaceFirst(new RegExp(r"\s+$"), "");
}
```

Comment: I also agree that these should just be String methods. Please star the bug linked to above.

Answer (score 1):

The library [MoreDart](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/more) has some Guava inspired helpers that allow you to efficiently trim strings from beginning, end, or both:

```dart
import 'package:more/char_matcher.dart';

...

var whitespace = new CharMatcher.whitespace();    // what to trim

whitespace.trimFrom(input);   // trim from beginning and end
whitespace.trimLeadingFrom(input);   // trim from beginning
whitespace.trimTrailingFrom(input);   // trim from end
```

Answer (score 1):

We just added `trimLeft` and `trimRight` to Quiver today, though it turns out that they are also being added to `String` in  future SDK release. You can use Quiver today though.

The difference between these implementations and the Regex-based solution is that the definition of whitespace is the same as `String.trim`. Regex's recognize fewer whitespace characters.

http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver