# String.trimLeft and trimRight in dart

Tags: string, dart, apache-commons-lang

How to define `trimLeft` and `trimRight` functions for `String`? I can't find a simple solution to implement them.

My tricky solution is:

```dart
String _trimLeft(String str) {
  var s = (str + '.').trim();
  return s.substring(0, s.length-1);
}

String _trimRight(String str) {
  return ('.' + str).trim().substring(1);
}
```

Is there any 3rd-party libraries for Dart just like `commons-lang` to java, provides such basic functions?

Comment: Please star http://dartbug.com/5589 - It should just be there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trimming whitespace in Dart strings from beginning or end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107905/trimming-whitespace-in-dart-strings-from-beginning-or-end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer that uses String.replace and a RegExp:

[Trimming whitespace in Dart strings from beginning or end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107905/trimming-whitespace-in-dart-strings-from-beginning-or-end)

I help maintain a general utility package called Quiver, but it doesn't have trim functions. They would be a great addition.

https://github.com/google/quiver-dart

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to match against a RegExp, but your solution looks simpler.

```
String _trimLeft(String str) {
  RegExp re = new RegExp(r"^\s*(.+)");
  return re.firstMatch(str).group(1);
}
```

(This code is **untested.**)

**Edit:** This question was asked & answered before. see [Trimming whitespace in Dart strings from beginning or end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107905/trimming-whitespace-in-dart-strings-from-beginning-or-end?rq=1)

Dart libraries are managed by [pub](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/) and available on http://pub.dartlang.org/packages